# Vuejs image src dynamic load doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I just started using Vue.js and Vue CLI and i'm facing an issue, i don't understand why i can't set the image dynamically from the scope but i can do it writing it directly in the HTML, obj.img is a string with `@/assets/logo.png` value too. I have a timeout faking an ajax call, but the browser does not resolve properly the routes for the image.

```
<div slot="media">
        <img :src="obj.img"> <!-- http://localhost:8080/@/assets/logo.png -->
        <img src="@/assets/logo.png"> <!-- http://localhost:8080/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png -->
</div>
```

Also, why are the routes different? Any ideas?

Comment: try this `./assets/logo.png` in you data object property

Comment: Because the packer is not using `require` under the hood on a computed property. Check the first answer under the first related question on the right ---->

Comment: ` <v-img :src="require(`@/assets/` +  items.image)" height="200px"></v-img>` this one also solved the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the real fix would be this:

```
:src="getImage(obj.img)"

getImage(path) {
  return require(path)
}
```

You can read more about it [in this response from Evan, the creator of Vue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126)

Comment: Apparently not possible to pass only a variable to `require`, so one of the solutions might be huge switch-case: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391#issuecomment-194581270  Also `return require(path + '')` seems to be working.

Comment: ` <v-img :src="require(`@/assets/` +  items.image)" height="200px"></v-img>` this one also solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Good!

Like @Ohgodwhy showed, Vue don't get the image path directly.

That's the way to get set an image src:

```
<v-img max-height="150" max-width="250" :src="getImage()"></v-img>
```

and then, in methods, you need a:

```
methods: {
    getImage() {
      return require("./logo.png");
    },
  },
```

And it's done! I'm a beginner and I got a lot to do with it.